# use linq to query dynamic object

Tags: c#, linq

I dynamically set the type of an object
Then I want to query that object

```
  int id = 123;
  dynamic b = 
    Convert.ChangeType(dataToCompareTo, Type.GetType(tableName));

 var values = (from item in (b)
                where item.Id == id
                select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Linq will not allow me to do this ("query expressions with source type of dynamic [..] are not allowed").  I do not know the object type before runtime.

Comment: what if you change `dynamic b =` with `var b =` have you tried that

Comment: @MethodMan how will that help?  b will then be an object with can't be used in the linq expression - which is expecting an IEnumerable

Comment: then the op would have to cast that object as `(IEnumerable)` would be my next guess

Comment: @MethodMan an important detail...

Comment: you are saying the same thing that I am and your answer supports that.. LOL

Comment: My read on both answers is that you are both expressing that dynamic is the wrong choice, and OP should cast object to correct choice. There's no real conflict here.

Comment: Use `var` instead of `dynamic`. By convention, all the queries performed by LINQ use implicit type local variables

Comment: @MethodMan I'm not disputing your point just that you missed quite an important detail.  The op is wanting to magically be able to make use of an object without casting, you can't do this with var or dynamic with ChangeType

Comment: @TimRutter point very well taken I cannot dispute that .. but I was just giving a quick and dirty fix without having to code a full blown fix / answer.. allowing the OP the opportunity to think outside the box `+1` on your answer btw

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic` is the wrong thing to use here. `ChangeType` has a return type of `object`.  It is not possible for the compiler to know at compile time what the type will be. If you define `b` as `var` the compiler will consider `b` to be an `object` and know nothing more about it.

Your LINQ expression seems to be expecting a particular type that implements `IEnumerable` and perhaps even an `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. In which case you would have to cast it to those types:

```
int id = 123;
var b = 
Convert.ChangeType(dataToCompareTo, Type.GetType(tableName));

IEnumerable<SomeType> c = b as IEnumerable<SomeType>;
if (c == null)
{
    ///this is where you handle the objects that aren't what you need them to be for the linq expression below
}
else
{
    var values = (from item in (c)
            where item.Id == id
            select item).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: .. trouble is I do not know the type until I get my import data as xml

Comment: So you have to then attempt the cast and if it fails do something else.  I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dynamic - you can do it here. Suppose you know that your `b` variable is list of some type which has `Id` property but you don't know which, and for whatever reason cannot use interface:

```
public class SomethingWithId {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
// you have no idea what that is at runtime
object something = new List<SomethingWithId>() {new SomethingWithId() {Id = id}};
```

Then you can use `dynamic` like this:

```
object something = new List<SomethingWithId>() {new SomethingWithId() {Id = id}};
// cast to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, this will always compile
// but of course might fail at runtime, as always with dynamic
// in your case that is (IEnumerable<dynamic>) Convert.ChangeType(dataToCompareTo, Type.GetType(tableName));
var b = (IEnumerable<dynamic>) something;
// run your query
var values = (from item in b
       where item.Id == id
       select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

That said - don't get used to do such things in C# - it's strongly typed languge and you should not ignore benefits provided by that.

Comment: I have yet to find any situation where the dynamic keyword is a good thing to use.

Comment: @TimRutter I don't use it myself also.